# Why Do Seed Sellers Mix Seeds Instead of Selling Them Separately?

Tags: seeds

I've noticed that many seed sellers offer mixed seed packs, where various types of seeds are blended together in one package. As a gardener, I'm curious about the rationale behind this practice.

Why do seed sellers choose to mix seeds instead of selling them separately? What are the benefits or advantages of selling mixed seeds?

I understand that mixing seeds can provide diversity and variety in a garden, but are there other reasons behind this approach? Additionally, are there any drawbacks or limitations to selling mixed seeds that sellers consider?

I'm interested in understanding the industry perspective on this matter and any insights from seed sellers or experts in horticulture would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is regional, at best. In the US, there are plenty of companies that sell seeds individually by species/cultivar. Germany's Jelitto Seeds does the same, although it's likely that it won't have the species you're probably looking for. Worth checking out, though.

Comment: One theory: As growers select desirable strains of plants, they have a surfeit of leftovers. The Party Best! New-Grower's Picks! Hybridizer's Selections! New and Improved Blues!

Comment: I suspect that the reasons are mainly financial, and/or uncertainty of the exact provinance of collected seeds.    Many people may not have large beds, and it does not pay to purchase lots of packets of seeds for variety in a small space, seller may want to get rid of excess seed.